# File parsing: C++ to cocoa

Tags: c++, file-io

Can anyone help me to convert this c++ function to cocoa?
Here I am parsing file line by line. I need to know efficient NS function

```
std::ifstream Stream;
Stream.open(FilePath,std::ios_base::in);

if (Stream.is_open()) 
{
    std::string Line;
    std::string Read, Key, Value;
    std::size_t i;
    while( !Stream.eof() ) {
        std::stringstream LineStream;
        std::getline( Stream, Line );
        printf("%s\n",Line);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert it?  When do you *require* Objective-C over C++?

Comment: I want to learn obj.C in depth. So wish to learn equal obj.C calls.

Comment: Slow response, but I understand.  For a client I re-wrote my CSV parser into Objective-C recently.  It was a good learning experience!

Comment: today one more downvte...so mentioned why I asked here.

Comment: Ah fair enough, have a +1 from me.  I see no reason for any downvoting here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

approximately:

```
NSString * file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; // or url
NSCharacterSet * newlineSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSArray * lines = [file componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlineSet];
for (NSString * at in lines) {
  printf("%s\n", [at UTF8String]);
}
[file release], file = 0;
```

but yes, like Goz mentioned: if it already works using c++, why convert it to objc?